# find correlation between all pairs in 2 files R

Tags: r, correlation

I have two matrices, one for snp genotypes and the other for cnv genotypes and I want to find the correlation between all snp-cnv pairs. For example, for each row in file 1, find the correlation with all rows in file 2.

The files look like this:

File 1:

```
snp1    2   0   2
snp2    2   1   2
snp3    2   1   2
```

File 2:

```
cnv1    2   1   2
cnv2    2   2   2
cnv3    2   2   1
```

I'm using R so far. This is what I have been working on:

```
snps <- read.table("snpsresults.txt", header=T, sep ="\t")
cnvs <- read.table("cnvs_genotypes2-9.txt", header=T, sep = "\t")
attach(snps)
attach(cnvs)

A <- as.matrix(t(snps))
B <- as.matrix(t(cnvs))

corr.matrix <- cor(A,B,use="pairwise.complete.obs", method="pearson")
write.table(corr.matrix, file="rs-values.txt"))
```

Expected output would be a table of all r-values for every snp.

snp1 -0.5
snp2 -0.5

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You may want to try and give your question a reproducable piece of code and a desired output. Its not clear to me exactly what you want but the functions  `match` and  `merge`  spring to mind.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you are asking so if you mind to edit and clarify your question you'd get much better help. I'm assuming you want to compute correlation of `snp` and `cnv` by rows (columns is standard). In principle all you need is:

```
cor(t(snp), t(cnv))
```

This will cast an error with your data as `cnv2` is constant and to compute correlation you demean (ok) and standardize (impossible here as standard deviation is zero) first. So here I slightly changed your example data:

```
snp = matrix(c(2,2,2, 0,1,1, 2,2,2), 3, 3)
cnv = matrix(c(2,3,2, 1,2,2, 2,2,1), 3, 3)
```

Now you get:

```
> snp
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    0    2
[2,]    2    1    2
[3,]    2    1    2
> cnv
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    1    2
[2,]    3    2    2
[3,]    2    2    1
> cor(t(snp), t(cnv))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1  0.5 -0.5
[2,]    1  0.5 -0.5
[3,]    1  0.5 -0.5
```

Note that this is constant per row since after demeaning and standardizing the rows of `snp` are all the same.

Comment: Sorry, I will re-phrase as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try mts.

Comment: I was using this approach but it creates a file too large to open. Thanks for you help though.